# MySQL 5.6 install on debian ERROR:

Tags: mysql, debian

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.6 on Debian.

Here what I do:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-5.6.12-debian6.0-i686.deb
cd /usr/local
ln -s /opt/mysql/server-5.6 mysql
cd mysql
scripts/mysql_install_db.sh --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
FATAL ERROR: Could not find @bindir@/my_print_defaults

If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.

If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
pointing to that location.
```

Could you please suggest something? I'm installing MySQL from scratch (previous version was completely removed).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not be able to help with the error you're getting. But `apt-get install -f mysql-server-5.5` worked for me on Debian Wheezy. Try replacing 5.5 with 5.6 and see if it works as well, and probably precede it with `sudo`.